# Custom UIHostingConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, collectionview

in iOS16, UIHostingConfiguration was newly introduced.

I tired to using it but meet a problems of margin.
I did not configure margin but that struct default values have a margin.
(not sure, but depend on size...)

so I add like this.

```swift
UIHostingConfiguration {
    ContentView()
}
.margin(.all, 0)
```

this code works well.
but I want to make a new init or new struct for removing
`.margin(.all, 0)` < --- this line.

I tired like bottom

```swift
extension UIHostingConfiguration {
    static func noMargin<Content: View>(content: @ViewBuilder () -> Content) -> UIHostingConfiguration {
        return UIHostingConfiguration(content: content)
            .margins(.all, 0)
    }
}
```

but it comes out error like this.

```
Cannot convert value of type '() -> Content' to expected argument type '() -> Content'
```

please tell me is there any good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `UIHostingConfiguration` has two generic type parameters - `Content` and `Background`

The [initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingconfiguration/init(content:)) of `UIHostingConfiguration` you are using requires that `Background` is `EmptyView`, i.e. the initialiser creates a configuration with no background. The background can be set later with the [`background`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingconfiguration/background(content:)) modifier.

If you call this initialiser without specifying type parameters, you are implicitly using `Self.Content` and `Self.Background`, and since you did not constrain `Self.Background`, it could be any `View`. For example, if I did:

```
UIHostingConfiguration<Text, Rectangle>.noMargins { ... }
```

then `Self.Background` would be `Rectangle`!

You can constrain `Self.Background` to fix this issue:

```
extension UIHostingConfiguration where Background == EmptyView
```

The consequence of implicitly using `Self.Content` is that `Self.Content` could be different from the `Content` type parameter of the `noMargins` method, which is why you get the seemingly nonsense "cannot convert from `() -> Content` to `() -> Content`" error. It's actually saying "cannot convert from `() -> Content` to `() -> Self.Content`".

To fix this, simply remove the `Content` type parameter from `noMargins`. Then the `content` view builder parameter would be of type `() -> Self.Content`.

```
extension UIHostingConfiguration where Background == EmptyView {
    static func noMargin(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> UIHostingConfiguration {
        return UIHostingConfiguration<Content, EmptyView>(content: content)
            .margins(.all, 0)
    }
}
```

---

Note that explicitly specifying the initialiser's type arguments also works, but then the caller of `noMargins` would also need to specify the type arguments of `UIHostingConfiguration`, since there is no other way to infer what `Content` and `Background` should be on the caller's side.

```
extension UIHostingConfiguration {
    static func noMargin<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> UIHostingConfiguration<Content, EmptyView> {
        return UIHostingConfiguration<Content, EmptyView>(content: content)
            .margins(.all, 0)
    }
}
```

Caller:

```
// Caller needs to put two random views as the type parameter. Anything will work.
UIHostingConfiguration<Text, Spacer>.noMargin {
    ...
}
```